# Reading line by line from one file and write to another file using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

In below code i am tring to fetch the line no of string "AXX0000XXXA" from file data.txt,then fetching line by line and printing target.txt file,in between if the line reach the find line no i am adding one more line from file temp.txt.The code is working fine with the less nos of records(tested with 150 lines-File Size 100 kb),but when i am processing with 50K records(File Size 25MB) it is taking more then 25 minutes to process.could you please help me how i will process same in less time.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "AXX0000XXXA" "C:\Users\23456\Desktop\data.txt"') do (set find_line=%%a)
set /a counter=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in (`"findstr /n ^^ C:\Users\23456\Desktop\data.txt"`) do ( 
set curr_line=%%b
set /a counter=!counter!+1 
if !counter! equ !find_line! (
    type temp.txt >> target.txt
)
call :print_line curr_line
)
endlocal

:print_line
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set line=!%1!
set line=!line:*:=!
echo !line!>>target.txt
endlocal
```

Comment: Is your question "why does it take a lot of time to process a lot of files?"

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses three Batch file constructs that are inherently slow: `call` command, `>>` append redirection and `setlocal/endlocal`, and these constructs are executed once per each file line! It would be faster to include the subroutine into the original code to avoid the `call` and `setlocal` commands, and an `echo !line!>>target.txt` command imply open the file, search for the end, append the data and close the file, so it is faster to use this construct: `(for ...) > target.txt` that just open the file once. An example of a code with such changes is in Compo's answer.

This is another method to solve this problem that may run faster when the search line is placed towards the beginning of the file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "AXX0000XXXA" "C:\Users\23456\Desktop\data.txt"') do (set /A find_line=%%a-1)
call :processFile < "C:\Users\23456\Desktop\data.txt" > target.txt
goto :EOF


:processFile

rem Duplicate the first %find_line%-1 lines
for /L %%i in (1,1,%find_line%) do (
   set /P "line="
   echo !line!
)

rem Insert the additional line
type temp.txt

rem Copy the rest of lines
findstr ^^

exit /B
```

Comment: Excellent! Processed 27Mb 50K-line file on my machine in 3 seconds.

Comment: @Aacini:thank you very much for your timly help,its processing very fast but some issue that some lines are broken into multiple lines in target.txt.one more that after type temp.txt ther is no line break,in same line the next lines started.

Comment: Yes. The `set /P` command can only read a maximum of 1023 characters, so any longer line is split in chuncks of 1023 characters each. I don't understand what is the concern with the temp.txt because the `type temp.txt` command I used is _exactly the same_ you used in your code...

Comment: Hi all..inside my file there is 1 line for 1 record and the length of line is more then 2500 char,afrer 1024 char the line broken into new line.could you please help me how to solve this with same logic.

Comment: Well, you need to understand first the limitations of `set /P` command. A working solution requires that **1-** the long line have a length that is not an exact multiple of 1023, and **2-** that each 1023 chunk in the long line does not start with spaces. If your file fulfill these requirements, please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46860695/edit) and insert a small section of the file (8-10 lines) that include both the long line and the "AXX0000XXXA" target line.

Answer (score 0):

This should create `target.txt` with content matching `data.txt` except for an inserted line taken from `tmp.txt` immediately above the line matching the search string, `AXX0000XXXA`.

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "fSrc=C:\Users\23456\Desktop\data.txt"
Set "iSrc=temp.txt"
Set "sStr=AXX0000XXXA"
Set "fDst=target.txt"

Set "iStr="
Set/P "iStr="<"%iSrc%" 2>Nul
If Not Defined iStr Exit/B

Set "nStr="
For /F "Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr/N "%sStr%" "%fSrc%" 2^>Nul') Do Set "nStr=%%A"
If Not Defined nStr Exit/B

(   For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr/N "^" "%fSrc%"') Do (
        If "%%A"=="%nStr%" Echo %iStr%
        Echo %%B))>"%fDst%"
```

I have made it easy for you to change your variable data, *you only need to alter lines 3-6*.

I have assumed that this was your intention, your question was not clear, please accept my apologies if I have assumed incorrectly.