# How can I insert a new string of text into a specific location in existing text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

I need to insert the following single line into an existing text file on many computers. Therefore, I need to automate this in a batch file.

**Line to add:**

```
<.add key="StudentAccountPaymentRunEnvironment" value="PRODUCTION"/>
```

The Destination for this string is in to a file called:  `O2-config.txt` and within the `O2-config.txt` file, I need to insert the line shown above, just after the line shown below:

```
<.add key="TuitionPaymentRunEnvironment" value="PRODUCTION"/.>
```

So the final result will be:

**Existing**

```
<.add key="TuitionPaymentRunEnvironment" value="PRODUCTION"/>
```

**New**

```
<.add key="StudentAccountPaymentRunEnvironment" value="PRODUCTION"/>
```

There are many lines of text preceding and following these two lines.  Please advise.  I searched and found solutions for `linux`, but not for a `Windows/Command Prompt`.  I want to put this solution in a `.bat` file that can execute with Windows Group Policy.

Comment: You may solve your problem using the same method described at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860695/reading-line-by-line-from-one-file-and-write-to-another-file-using-batch-script/46863531#46863531)

Comment: Your Existing line once has a dot near the end and once **NOT**?

Comment: I don't think the reformatting helps in all areas. The **existing** and **new** headings don't make it clear that the new line is to be appended after the existing one. The "final result" (per the text) should show the two lines together, as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 comes with PowerShell, so you could use:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\12\07\SO_53661614.ps1
$Ins = [RegEx]::escape('<.add key="TuitionPaymentRunEnvironment" value="PRODUCTION"/>')
$New = [RegEx]::escape('<.add key="StudentAccountPaymentRunEnvironment" value="PRODUCTION"/>')
(Get-Content .\yourfile.txt) -replace $Ins,($Ins+"`n"+$new)|Set-Content .\yourfile.txt
```

Wrapping this in a batch :

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\12\07\SO_53661614.cmd
Set "Ins=<.add key="TuitionPaymentRunEnvironment" value="PRODUCTION"/>"
Set "New=<.add key="StudentAccountPaymentRunEnvironment" value="PRODUCTION"/>"
Powershell -Nop -C "(Get-Content .\yourfile.txt).replace($ENV:Ins,$ENV:Ins+\"`n\"+$ENV:New)|Set-Content .\yourfile.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a Windows port of sed [from this site](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net).

Using that, you can execute this command:

`sed -i "s/<.add key=.TuitionPaymentRunEnvironment. value=.PRODUCTION.\/>/&\n<.add key=\"StudentAccountPaymentRunEnvironment\" value=\"PRODUCTION\"\/>/" somefile.txt`

And after that, the line-endings need to be repaired:

`sed -i ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\r\n/g" somefile.txt`

Note that I'm assuming there is only one instance of that text in your file.

For a solution that only modifies the first match of that string, you can put this into a batch file:

```
set MATCH=.add key=.TuitionPaymentRunEnvironment. value=.PRODUCTION.
sed "0,/%MATCH%/ {s/%MATCH%\/>/&\n<.add key=\"StudentAccountPaymentRunEnvironment\" value=\"PRODUCTION\"\/>/}" somefile.txt > temp.txt
sed ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\r\n/g" temp.txt > somefile.txt
del temp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For a **PURE BATCH** solution we can use an `for` loop along with an `if` statement to find the first string then on the very next line insert a pre-defined phrase.

Bellow you can configure in the file name (Or incorporate a loop to search multiple files), search string, and the line to add string. Please keep not that on the line to add string you take care of any special charecters such as the `<` & `>` by using the escape character `^`. Example: `^<`. The Base Original script is by [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15919579/8667430).

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem | Configuration
Set "FileToEdit=O2-config.txt"
Set "LineToFind=<.add key="TuitionPaymentRunEnvironment" value="PRODUCTION"/>"
Set "LineToPutAfter=^<.add key="StudentAccountPaymentRunEnvironment" value="PRODUCTION"/^>"

Rem | Check If "FileToEdit" Exists
if not exist "%FileToEdit%" (
    echo File "%FileToEdit%" Not Found!
    pause
    goto :EOF
)
goto StartFunction

:StartFunction

Rem | Export SearchString
echo !LineToFind!>> %~dp0LineToFind.txt

Rem | Add Text Under %LineToFind%
(
    FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (LineToFind.txt) DO (
    SET AddAfter=%%i

    FOR /f "delims=" %%n IN ('findstr /n "^" %FileToEdit%') DO (
        SET line=%%n
        SET line=!line:*:=!

        ECHO(!line!
            IF "!line!"=="!AddAfter!" ECHO(%LineToPutAfter%
        )
    )
)>>%FileToEdit%.TEMP

Rem | Remove LineToFind.txt
DEL LineToFind.txt

Rem | Delete Original File, Restore New
DEL %FileToEdit%
REN %FileToEdit%.TEMP %FileToEdit%

goto :EOF
```

**Input Example:**

```
<.add key="Test1" value="PRODUCTION"/>
<.add key="Test2" value="PRODUCTION"/>
<.add key="Test3" value="PRODUCTION"/>
<.add key="Test4" value="PRODUCTION"/>
<.add key="TuitionPaymentRunEnvironment" value="PRODUCTION"/>
<.add key="Test5" value="PRODUCTION"/>
<.add key="Test6" value="PRODUCTION"/>
```

**Output Example:**

```
<.add key="Test1" value="PRODUCTION"/>
<.add key="Test2" value="PRODUCTION"/>
<.add key="Test3" value="PRODUCTION"/>
<.add key="Test4" value="PRODUCTION"/>
<.add key="TuitionPaymentRunEnvironment" value="PRODUCTION"/>
<.add key="StudentAccountPaymentRunEnvironment" value="PRODUCTION"/>
<.add key="Test5" value="PRODUCTION"/>
<.add key="Test6" value="PRODUCTION"/>
```

For help on any of the commands do the following:

- `call /?`
- `set /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `find /?`
- So on.